# Map Reduce Programe gives only Mapper Output

Tags: mapreduce

This is my first program in map/reduce. Instead of traditional word count program I tried to count no.of vowels and consonants in a file. Below is my code.

Mapper:

public class VowelConsMapper extends Mapper {

```
public void map(LongWritable mapKey,Text mapValue,Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{

    String line = mapValue.toString();
    String[] letters = line.split("");

    for(String letter : letters){
        System.out.println(letter);
        if(letter!=" "){
            if(isVowel(letter))
                context.write(new Text("Vowel"), new IntWritable(1));
            else
                context.write(new Text("Consonant"), new IntWritable(1));
        }
    }
}

private boolean isVowel(String letter) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(letter.equalsIgnoreCase("a")||letter.equalsIgnoreCase("e")||letter.equalsIgnoreCase("i")||letter.equalsIgnoreCase("o")||letter.equalsIgnoreCase("u"))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

}

Reducer:

```
public class VowelConsReducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
    public void reducer(Text letterType,Iterable<IntWritable> values,Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
        int sum = 0;
        for(IntWritable value:values){
            sum += value.get();
        }
        System.out.println(letterType+"     "+sum);
        context.write(letterType, new IntWritable(sum));
    }
}
```

Driver:

public class VowelConsDriver {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException, ClassNotFoundException {

    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    conf.addResource(new Path("/home/hadoop/hadoop-1.0.3/conf/core-site.xml"));
    Job job = new Job(conf,"VowelConsDriver");

    job.setJarByClass(VowelConsDriver.class);
    job.setMapperClass(VowelConsMapper.class);
    job.setReducerClass(VowelConsReducer.class);

    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    // TODO: specify output types
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path("/user/hadoop/WCinput"));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("/user/hadoop/VowelConsOP1"));

    job.waitForCompletion(true);
}
```

}

It is giving following o/p:
Consonant      1
Consonant      1
Consonant      1
...............
...............
...............
................
...............
...............
vowel          1
vowel          1
vowel          1
vowel          1
...............
...............
...............
................
...............
...............

where as I'm expecting consonants & vowels total number for each category
Sorry if I didn't format the code correctly... & Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The signature of the reduce is method is "`public void reduce()`" not "`public void reducer()`"
The above change will give you the expected output!

Answer (score 0):

The line that starts

```
public void reducer(
                  ^
```

should be

```
@Override
public void reduce(
```

*Your* intended reducer isn't being invoked because you [misnamed the method](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Reducer.html#reduce%28KEYIN,%20java.lang.Iterable,%20org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.Context%29), so instead you're getting the [default implementation](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/src-html/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Reducer.html#line.147). The default implementation just dumps the keys and values out:

```
for(VALUEIN value: values) {
    context.write((KEYOUT) key, (VALUEOUT) value);
}
```

In your case, the key / value pairs are `("Vowel", 1)` or `("Consonant", 1)` so this explains your output.

This is why you *should always* use the [`@Override` annotation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html) when you're overriding a method. The compiler would have told you that `reducer` actually isn't overriding any method.